# For which reasons a manifest is used in the .net world

Tags: .net, dll, manifest

I remember 10 years ago a manifest was used to resolve the "dll hell", it specifies an assemmbly/collection of dll's with a specific version.
I have seen some .net surces which defines a manifest and embedded it via mt.exe in the dll.
Do anybody know for which reasons the manifest and it's meta data are used in the .net world?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about the [Assembly Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/assembly-manifest), it's all written in the official documentation:

> Each assembly's manifest performs the following functions:
>
> - Enumerates the files that make up the assembly.
> - Governs how references to the assembly's types and resources map to the files that contain their declarations and implementations.
> - Enumerates other assemblies on which the assembly depends.
> - Provides a level of indirection between consumers of the assembly and the assembly's implementation details.
> - Renders the assembly self-describing.